# Error Message while opening the Visual Studio Installer of VS community 2017

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

After downloading the vs_community.exe from Official Microsoft Visual Studio and installing the Visual Studio Installer, when I clicked it and it shows like this:
[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMyzv.jpg).
So how could I fix this?

Comment: Hi, I found the error code '0x80004005', it often means the installer is corrupted, please access this: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ and sign in with your Microsoft account, freely join the Dev Essentials, then download the latest VS 2015 version: Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3 to install. Before the installation, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software, clean up the %temp% folder and run the installer as administrator, if this issue persists, please collect the installation log and share, thanks.

Comment: @Jim Kaku, I agree with Heath's suggestion, based on the error message, maybe it would be related to your command line, if possible, please share us the detailed steps/command about how you install your VS. In addition, as far as I know, some command line parameters to install VS2017 also has the version requirements, so please really download the latest setup version for your VS. Any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line you passed is incorrect. It would help to know exactly what you passed on the command line.